# Is this pattern is alright?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using modal with the new pattern called 'render hooks'

This looks like this:

```
const useModal = ({content}) => {
  const renderModal = () => <Modal>{content}</Modal>

  return { renderModal };
}
```

And I'm wondering this pattern is alright. I think this is similar to the re-declaring component in another component.

Comment: Looks weird to me. You're basically returning a component from a hook. So what use the hook in he first place?

Comment: I've never heard of "render hooks". And this just looks bizarre. Also hooks aren't usually for rendering components, they're for sharing functionality between components. Seems like you should just be using a regular component or HOC for this. What's your goal here?

Comment: @cbdeveloper Thanks. I just wondered this is alright. If everyone feels weird, I think this pattern is not alright.

Comment: @Jayce444 Actually, this code snippet is the really short version of my actual usage. I usually define more complex functions that handle the modal. And now I think this pattern is not alright. THX!

Answer (score 0):

The reason custom hooks start with the prefix 'use' is to indicate the facts:

1. its a hook and 2. it contains react default hooks: useState, useEffect and so on.
   What is offered here is a factory function for a component. It not a hook by all means. I would not recommend using it.

Comment: I think I wrote too simple example. I usually define more complex things and functions that handle the modal. For example, useState for manage title and content for modal, handleModal function for handling the modal, and so on.

If I wrote more things in this custom hooks, Do you think this pattern is alright?

Comment: So basically you write a component as a hook?

Comment: I think I didn't.. but on the other hand, right.

I wanted to render some component without `import` statement. So I found this pattern. But now I think this is almost component/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a component which renders its content based on props . so why not just this

```
const CustomModal = ({content}) => ( <Modal>{content}</Modal>) ;
```

Comment: Actually, this code snippet is a really short version of my actual usage.  I usually define more complex things and functions that handle the modal. For example, `useState` for manage title and content for modal, `handleModal` function for handling the modal, and so on.

And not I think the CustomModal component and custom hook for it is better. THX!